Finding amplitude, period, and shift of the given graph
A problem in a Mathematics book that I have. Notice, still learning, please do not overreact.
Definition: $f(x) = A\sin \left[k\left(x + B^\circ\right)\right]$
Find the amplitude, period, and movement of the following graph.

My attempt to understand where to approach the period from

The final answer in the book is:
$A = 1, k = 1, B = 30^\circ, f(x) = \sin(x + 30^\circ)$

The graph is shifted to the left by $30^\circ$. Hence, we put a $+30^\circ$ in the argument of $\sin$. If it was shifted to the right by $30^\circ$, we would put a $-30^\circ$ in the argument of $\sin$. You can verify this by substituting $x=0^\circ$ in the equation.

How do you see this? I did draw the graph, and tried approaching it from the two instances below, see second screenshot.

If the graph was of $\sin{x}$, it would cut the x-axis at the origin, i.e., $f(x)=0$ at $x=0^\circ$. However, this graph cuts the x-axis at a point $30^\circ$ left of the origin, i.e., at $x=-30^\circ$. To include the information that $f(x)=0$ at this point, we use $\sin({x+30^\circ})$ instead of $\sin{x}$

I arrived to: $240^\circ - (-120^\circ) = 360^\circ$, however, I am confused by finding the actual period.

@AbigailJohnsson This is correct $240-(-120)=360=2\pi$ in indeed the period.

Isn't that simply the graph of $\sin(x - \arcsin(0.5))$? :-)

From the graph we have that

maximum is $1$ therefore $A=1$;
period is $240°-(-120°)=360° \implies k=1$ (see addendum here below);
at $x=0$ the function is equal to $\frac12=\sin (30°) \implies B=30$.

Note that we could also have the equivalent solution $A=-1$, $k=-1$, $B=-30°= 330°$.

To clarify your confusion, let consider the case with $k=2$ and $B=0$, that is $\sin(2x)$. What is the period?
Note that $\sin [2(x + 360°)]=\sin (2x)$ but also $\sin [2(x + 180°)]=\sin (2x)$, this means that period with $k=2$ is $360°/k=180°$.
Since in your case period is $360°$, this means that $k=1$.

More in general for $f(x)$ with (minimum) period $T$ we have for all $x$
$$f(x+T)=f(x)$$
then for $f(kx)$ we have
$$f\left[k(x+T_k)\right]=f(kx+kT_k) =f(kx)$$
when
$$kT_k=T \implies T_k=\frac T k$$

I found this too, with the period, but, was deeply confused in my head.  $240^\circ - (-120^\circ) = 360^\circ$, how did you find the $B^\circ$?

For the K you take $360^\circ / 240^\circ$ right?

@AbigailJohnsson Once you know that $A=1$ and period $= 360°$, you only need to look at $x=0$ and since $f(0)=1/2$ we have $f(0)=\sin 30°$ (checking also that $f$ is increasing at $x=0$).

I DO NOT understand!

@AbigailJohnsson No, factor $k\neq 1$ would change the period, but since period is $360°$ this means that $k=1$.

@AbigailJohnsson Consider the case $k=2$ for $\sin(2x)$. What is the period? Note that $\sin (2(x + 360°)=\sin 2x$ but also $\sin (2(x + 180°)=\sin 2x$, this mean that period with $k=2$ is $360°/k=180°$.

We wish to compare the given graph with the graph of the sine function $y = \sin x$.

You were given the graph shown below:

The amplitude of the graph is found by taking half of the difference between the maximum value and the minimum value.
$$|A| = \frac{\text{maximum value} - \text{minimum value}}{2} = \frac{1 - (-1)}{2} = \frac{2}{2} = 1$$
The period of a sinusoidal graph can be found by finding the distance between successive maxima or successive minima.  You correctly found the period by finding the distance between successive minima.
$$P = 240^\circ - (-120^\circ) = 360^\circ$$
The frequency of the graph, denoted by $k$ in your formula $f(x) = A\sin[k(x + B)]$, is the number of periods of the graph that occur within one period of $y = \sin x$.
$$k = \frac{360^\circ}{P} = \frac{360^\circ}{360^\circ} = 1$$
To determine the phase shift (horizontal shift), let's examine what happens when we superimpose the graph of $y = \sin x$ on the given graph.

It appears we can obtain the given graph from the graph of $y = \sin x$ by shifting the graph of $y = \sin x$ by $30^\circ$ to the left.  Since both the given graph and $y = \sin x$ open upwards, we can set $A = 1$, which suggests that the given graph has equation
$$f(x) = \sin(x + 30^\circ)$$
where $x$ is measured in degrees, so $B = 30^\circ$.
We can check if we are correct by checking whether our equation corresponds to the known points on the graph.  Observe that
$$f(0^\circ) = \sin(0^\circ + 30^\circ) = \sin(30^\circ) = 0.5$$
which agrees with the $y$-intercept.
Observe that
$$f(60^\circ) = \sin(60^\circ + 30^\circ) = \sin(90^\circ) = 1$$
which agrees with the maximum shown on the graph.
Observe that
$$f(-120^\circ) = \sin(-120^\circ + 30^\circ) = \sin(-90^\circ) = -1$$
which agrees with the minimum shown on the graph.
Similarly, you can verify that the equation also yields $(240^\circ, -1)$.
